# Fixed Header Scrollable Table - How to preserve horizontal scroll position using css jquery on page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header scrolling table with horizontal and vertical scroll bars, for which I can presently sort on each column **but am unable to properly preserve horizontal position of the table when loading the page**.

Using the following inline css I get `scrollAmount` from php from a hidden input whose value is from a jquery code and input it into the inline css

```
style="transform:translateX(<negative offset value of scrollAmount>)"
```

**My question is how do I properly maintain scroll position for a table that overflows with a horizontal scroll bar using CSS and jQuery without waiting for the page to completely load / finish rendering?**

**Inline style**

```
transform:translateX(-<?=scrollAmount()?>px)
```

**jQuery Scroll Position Function**

```
function setScroll(id_header, id_table)
        {
             $('div.'+id_table).on("scroll", function(){  //activate when #center scrolls
                    var left = $('div.'+ id_table).scrollLeft();  //save #center position to var left
                   $('div.'+id_header).scrollLeft(left);        //set #top to var left
                   $('#scrollamount').val(left);
                });
```

**Hidden Input HTML Code**

```
<input type="hidden" id="scrollamount" name="scrollamount" value=<?=scrollAmount()?>"/>
```

**PHP Code**

```
 function scrollAmount()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['scrollamount']))
            return $_POST['scrollamount'];
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Please read [the documentation for `scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/). It returns a number, which is the number of pixels.

Comment: I have revised my original question about the scrollLeft issue which, after reading the documentation, was confirmed to produce the desired result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code, I was able to produce a visually acceptable solution that keeps the table horizontally offset by the user's scrolled amount.

**JS Code - Executes on document.ready() when table has finished fetching/loading**

```
//Translate 0px, undoing the original translation       
$('table#'+ id_table).attr("style", "transform:translateX(0px)");   
$('table#'+ id_header).attr("style", "transform:translateX(0px)");  

//Scroll left to the desired amount as defined in the hidden input `#scrollamount` 
$('div.'+ id_table).scrollLeft($('#scrollamount').val());
$('div.'+ id_header).scrollLeft($('#scrollamount').val());
```

**HTML / PHP Code - Fixed Header Scrolling Table (Header and Table Body)**

```
<div class="summary_header">
<table id="summary_header" border=1 style="transform:translateX(-<?=scrollAmount()?>px)">
    ... <-----Table Header Definition
</table>
</div>

<div class="summary_table" style="overflow-x:scroll">     
<table id="summary_table" style="transform:translateX(-<?=scrollAmount()?>px)">
    ... <--Table Body Definition
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.scrollLeft()` will change every time you scroll, so you're simply setting it to where it's scrolled to. You could probably find the position of the table [with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/position/), set that to a universal variable at the start, and then later use `$('div.'+id_header).scrollLeft(globalLeftPosition)` to set it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way I can initialize the scroll position before the table/page finishes loading?    I tried using translate but it does not seem to have the desired outcome.

Comment: I'm not sure there is. A somewhat ugly way that could work would be to save the scrollLeft() of the window initially, set it to 0, get the position, then set it back (or, if you'd rather, leave out the first and last steps and just force the user to have the page scrolled to the left at the start).