# How do I prevent page flicker in IE which does not appear in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flicker

I have a page that relies on translation in 2d to move a table to the right of the screen if my scroll position before page resubmit is scrolled to the right.

The effect I am trying to capture is a table that is scrolled to the right when sorting the table (fixed header, limited height body, overflow scroll).

Firefox, even surprisingly Edge does not flicker, only IE flickers when I use this effect.

How do I suppress the artifacts of my CSS translation to eliminate this annoying IE page flicker?

This is related to a previous post I created with code provided.

[Fixed Header Scrollable Table - How to preserve horizontal scroll position using css jquery on page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890473/fixed-header-scrollable-table-how-to-preserve-horizontal-scroll-position-using/37902175#37902175)

**jQuery**

```
   function setScroll(id_header, id_table)
    {
         $('div.'+id_table).on("scroll", function(){  //activate when #center scrolls
                var left = $('div.'+ id_table).scrollLeft();  //save #center position to var left
               $('div.'+id_header).scrollLeft(left);        //set #top to var left
               $('#scrollamount').val(left);
            });

        $('table#'+ id_table).attr("style", "transform:translateX(0px)");   
         $('table#'+ id_header).attr("style", "transform:translateX(0px)");   
        $('div.'+ id_table).scrollLeft($('#scrollamount').val());
        rows = $('#summary_table tr').length;
        if(rows > 1)
        {
            $('div.'+ id_table).attr("style", "overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 250px !important");
        } 
        else if(rows == 1)
        {
            $('div.overlay div.'+ id_header).attr("style", "overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: none; width: 783px !important");
            $('div.overlay div.'+ id_table).attr("style", "overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: none; width: 783px !important");
        } 
        $('div.'+ id_header).scrollLeft($('#scrollamount').val());
    }
```

**HTML Table**

```
 <div class="summary_header">
        <table border="1" id="summary_header" style=
        "transform:translateX(0px)">
            <thead class="header">
                <tr>
                    <th class="edit" style="min-width: 34px; max-width:34px">
                    Edit</th>
                    <th style="min-width:34px; max-width:34px">
                    <nobr><a onclick="$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=ActionItemID&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    ID</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:449.86px; max-width:449.86px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=ActionItemTitle&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    ActionItemTitle</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:105.34px; max-width:105.34px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=Criticality&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    Criticality</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:123.16px; max-width:123.16px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=Assignor&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    Assignor</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:123.16px; max-width:123.16px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=Owner&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    Owner</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:129.1px; max-width:129.1px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=AltOwner&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    AltOwner</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:123.16px; max-width:123.16px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=Approver&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    Approver</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:111.28px; max-width:111.28px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=AssignedDate&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    AssignedDate</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:99.4px; max-width:99.4px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=DueDate&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    DueDate</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:99.4px; max-width:99.4px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=ECD&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    ECD</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:123.16px; max-width:123.16px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=CompletionDate&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    CompletionDate</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:99.4px; max-width:99.4px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=ClosedDate&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    ClosedDate</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:93.46px; max-width:93.46px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=Category1&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    Category1</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:93.46px; max-width:93.46px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=Category2&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    Category2</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:93.46px; max-width:93.46px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=Category3&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    Category3</a> <span style=
                    'display: inline-block; width: 13'></span></nobr></th>
                    <th style="min-width:93.46px; max-width:93.46px">
                    <nobr><a onclick=
                    "$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=Category4&dir=DESC&load=1');$('#summaryform').submit();">
                    Category4</a> &#9650;</nobr></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="summary_table overflow_table" style="overflow-x:hidden">
        <table border="1" id="summary_table" style="transform:translateX(0px)">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="row_even" id="row1">
                    <td class="edit" style="min-width: 34px; max-width:34px">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                    <!--input type="submit" value="Edit" style="width:60;height:20; border:none;font-weight: bold" /-->
                     </td>
                    <td style="min-width:34px; max-width:34px">
                    <nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:449.86px; max-width:449.86px">
                    <nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:105.34px; max-width:105.34px">
                    <nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:123.16px; max-width:123.16px">
                    <nobr><span>&nbsp;</span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:123.16px; max-width:123.16px">
                    <nobr><span>&nbsp;</span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:129.1px; max-width:129.1px">
                    <nobr><span></span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:123.16px; max-width:123.16px">
                    <nobr><span>&nbsp;</span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:111.28px; max-width:111.28px">
                    <nobr><span class="">&nbsp;</span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:99.4px; max-width:99.4px">
                    <nobr><span class="">&nbsp;</span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:99.4px; max-width:99.4px">
                    <nobr><span class="">&nbsp;</span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:123.16px; max-width:123.16px">
                    <nobr><span class="">&nbsp;/span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:99.4px; max-width:99.4px">
                    <nobr><span class=""></span></nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:93.46px; max-width:93.46px">
                    <nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:93.46px; max-width:93.46px">
                    <nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
                    <td style="min-width:93.46px; max-width:93.46px">
                    <nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
                    <td class='sort' style=
                    "min-width:93.46px; max-width:93.46px">
                    <nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setScroll('summary_header', 'summary_table');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code please, it will need the minimum amount of code equired to incororate the issue you are having, without any code we are unable to help

Answer (score 2):

Since I couldn't deduce the version of IE I will assume it to be >10 so if you want fine control over your animations I recommend using `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: Thank you for the response,. Just to clarify, my flickering artifact is when the page shows the horizontal translation instead of hiding it.  I have not used requestAnimationFrame before.  I want to avoid seeing the in between horizontal translation (that is, translate left and then translate right)  when sorting on the right most table header cells.

Comment: The whole point of my example was to preserve scroll on page reload, and without flickering.  I had difficulty to achieve the above objective with the mentioned suggestion.  I was unsure how to use it if it would solve the issue.